# Local Debugging of Azure Functions with Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've configured my UWP app to authenticate using a MobileServiceClient. This appears to be working fine. The ClaimsPrincipal object is authenticated when executing remotely. However, I'm unable to retrieve the ClaimsPrincipal from my Azure Function when debugging locally.

I believe this is because I need to configure my local server with a matching SigningKey, ValidAudiences, and ValidIssuers settings; as described in this [article](http://www.systemsabuse.com/2015/12/04/local-debugging-with-user-authentication-of-an-azure-mobile-app-service/) covering Mobile App Services.

But I'm working with Azure Functions and not a Mobile App Service, and configuration appears to work differently.

How can I configure my local server to correctly interpret the credentials passed from my mobile app?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the reason it works remotely and not locally is because the Azure Functions local tooling does not currently support the Authentication / Authorization identity features. Until it does you'll need to find a way to mock the ClaimsPrincipal for local development/testing.

UPDATE: Same answer for Sept. 2020. We've done some work to get closer to this goal, but still not quite there yet.

Comment: Hi Chris, I just landed here from google. Do you know if the Azure Functions local debugging support for ClaimsPrincipal is supported now?

Comment: Hey @VardhamanDeshpande, unfortunately plans changed and we still haven't been able to complete the local Authentication / Authorization for the local tooling yet. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Hi @ChrisGillum,

Any news from this feature request? As far as I see, we still cannot localy proof test the authentication part. This makes adoption of the authentication quite complicated (mainly to validate available Claims). Thanks,